# Search in Array of Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, search

I have arrays like this:

```
Array
(
    [license_id] => 2
    [email_address] => alib@email.com
    [user_id] => 2
    [first_watch] => 
)
Array
(
    [license_id] => 1
    [email_address] => user1@email.com
    [user_id] => 
    [first_watch] => 
)
```

These arrays will be embedded in an array, so the result is an array of arrays.
I need to search within these items for a specific user_id.
so for instance i want to find out if the big array includes an array that has the user_id = 2 and return the key of that array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [license_id] => 2
            [email_address] => alib@email.com
            [user_id] => 2
            [first_watch] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [license_id] => 1
            [email_address] => user1@email.com
            [user_id] => 
            [first_watch] => 
        )
)
```

What I want from this example would the key, [0] if I'm looking for 2 (user_id). I'll be always looking for a user_id so that's fixed.
I used foreach to loop through items and in_array() to find the item, but the result is not always as I expect, sometimes searching for something that doesn't exist will still return a key.

You guys have any suggestions on achieving this?

Comment: Could you show your foreach loop you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

```
//my_array being your multidimensional array
//my_id being the id you're looking for
$index = null;
for($i=0;$i<count($my_array);$i++)
{
   //is the id in this sub array?
   if($my_array[$i]['user_id'] == $my_id)
   {
      //get the index you're searching for
      $index = $i;
   }
}
//check if an index was found
if($index != null)
{
   //display the index you're searching for
   echo $index;
}
```

It's a little bit long but it allows you to do add stuff to the code if you need to.

Comment: Maybe change license-id to user ID? That's what the OP want. Other than that , you did a great job!! I love loopings.

Answer (score 5):

**PHP >= 5.5.0**

Extract the `user_id` column and search:

```
$key = array_search(2, array_column($array, 'user_id'));
```

**PHP < 5.5.0**

Map and get `user_id`:

```
$key = array_search(2, array_map(function($v) { return $v['user_id']; }, $array));
```

Or loop and check:

```
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    if($v['user_id'] == 2) {
        $key = $k;
        break;
    }
}
```